# How the accuracy of glm binomial model in Caret calculated?

Tags: r, r-caret, glm

I am training  glm binomial model in caret to do fraud classification (0 means nonfraud, and 1 means fraud):

```
model.lr <- train(fraud_ind ~ var1 + var2 + var3,
                  data = d_train, method = 'glm', family = 'binomial', trControl=tr_ctrl
```

I see the model output:

```
> model.lr
Generalized Linear Model 

90826 samples
    3 predictors
    2 classes: '0', '1' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (15 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 84772, 84771, 84770, 84772, 84771, 84770, ... 
Resampling results:

  Accuracy  Kappa   
  0.866818  0.733636
```

I suppose the accuracy has to be related with some threshold, but the model didn't show me which threshold it used to do the classification.  Any idea of how exactly this accuracy is based on?

Comment: It used a cutoff of 0.5.

Comment: @missuse thanks. I think 0.5 is correct. I actually did some detailed analysis to predict the result using type='prob' and type='raw'. and find that the cutoff is 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Follow ups:

After I posted my question, I did some detailed analysis by compare the predicted probability and classification results.

> u=predict(model.lr, d_train, type='raw')
>
> v=predict(model.lr, d_train, type='prob')
>
> w <- data.frame(u, v)
>
> View(w)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOOzZ.jpg)

In the picture, the X1 is the predicted probability of 'fraud', and X0 is the probability on 'nonfraud'.  the first column U is the binary classification results. We can see clearly that the cutoff is at 0.5.